# How do you use Notify OSD in Razor Qt?

Tags: notify-osd, razorqt

Is it possible to set Razor Qt to use notify-osd instead of its built in notification system?

Comment: I thought notification is freedesktop standard (using dbus...). I renamed `/usr/bin/razor-notificationd` then killed its running daemon. then launched `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd &`. Tested from "Razor Notification Configuration", Clicked "Test Notification" button. It works! Did I miss something? or if you have tested it already, Doesn't it work with all type of notification?

Comment: @DKBose the built in system is intrusive and not consistent (sometimes notifications don't show at all, sometimes they don't go away until you click them, sometimes they let clicks pass through. And yes, it is now part of LXQt but that is irrelevant.

Comment: @Sneetsher I haven't tested that yet. You should have posted an answer btw.

Comment: @DKBose it isn't relevant because in Ubuntu 14.04 (and possibly 13.10), Razor Qt is in the repositories and thus supported. LXQt hasn't diverged enough anyway to make this question's answer be any different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop notification is freedesktop standard (using dbus). See [Desktop Notifications Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/). It should be a easy to replace.

The following procedure works for me in Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Rename  `razor-notificationd`

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/bin/razor-notificationd /usr/bin/razor-notificationd.orig
   ```
2. Make a symbolic link to `notify-osd` (to replace `razor-notificationd`)

   For 64bit edition:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd /usr/bin/razor-notificationd
   ```

   For 32bit edition:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/notify-osd /usr/bin/razor-notificationd
   ```
3. Kill its running daemon.

   ```
   pkill -f razor-notificationd
   ```
4. Check using:

   Razor Configuration Center → Razor Notification Configuration → Click "Test Notification" button

Notification using razor-notificationd (Before)

[image: Notification using razor-notificationd]

Notification using notify-osd (After)

[image: Notification using notify-osd]

Comment: @DKBose, I have updated answer to reflect that, indicating the used Ubuntu version 14.04 and may be better with result screen-shot. Thank you

Comment: I tested it and it works perfectly. One suggestion I have is to update the answer so you provide the paths for both 32 and 64 bit systems. Otherwise, perfect.